# Is there a shortcut for deleting a line in Jupyter's edit mode?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter's edit mode, is there a shortcut for deleting a line of text? Something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Visual Studio?

Comment: Any idea how I could recover the "delete line" behavior of `control`+`d` in Jupyter lab on ubuntu? For reasons unknown (updates?), this shortcut spontaneously changed to "highlight current word" a few weeks ago, and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or both, depending on version.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is listed under `Help` → `Keyboard Shortcuts` in the notebook menu, but <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> seems to work despite being undocumented.

Comment: Functionality is slightly different for me (on my Mac): Ctrl+D or Cmd+D delete the whole line (so that the edited cell shrinks by one line) whereas Shift+Delete (Cmd+Delete on Mac) only clears all text left of the cursor.

Comment: Any idea how I could recover the "delete line" behavior of `control`+`d` in Jupyter lab on ubuntu? For reasons unknown (updates?), this shortcut spontaneously changed to "highlight current word" a few weeks ago, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Figured it out: On Linux, there is a bug in jupyterlab versions `4.0.0` and higher that breaks the delete-line shortcut. For now (20230622) one must downgrade (`pip3 install --user jupyterlab==3.6.4`) as a temporary fix.

Answer (score 1):

As for Jupyter notebook servion version 6.0.2 the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> works for me. This shortcut is listed in the shortcut documentation, that can be found under `Help` → `Keyboard Shortcuts`.

If you want to edit the shortcuts you can do this here: `Help` → `Edit Keyboard Shortcuts`

Comment: This suddenly stopped working for me in Jupyter Lab. It's not clear specifically how one could add a "delete line" shortcut back from the settings or advanced settings editor.

Comment: Figured it out: On Linux, there is a bug in jupyterlab versions `4.0.0` and higher that breaks the delete-line shortcut. For now (20230622) one must downgrade (`pip3 install --user jupyterlab==3.6.4`) as a temporary fix.

Comment: Great to hear that you solved it!

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Actually both work for me on Mac