# How could i delete several lines of code at the same time in Jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to delete/tab several lines of code at the same time in Jupiter notebook. how could i do that? Is there hot keys for that?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809696/is-there-a-shortcut-for-deleting-a-line-in-jupyters-edit-mode/49809697

Answer (score 1):

1. While in the notebook, click to the left of the grey input box where it says In []: (You'll see the highlight color go from green to blue)
2. While it's blue, hold down shift and use your up arrow key to select the rows above or below
3. Press D twice
4. Click back into the cell and the highlight will turn back to green.